# How to generate a ciphered html URL in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

Creating an intranet application, in which URL will be sent to the user via Email(outlook). This URL should be generated using cipher(need a randon URL based on his Email/Emp ID) and through this URL user should be able to login into account. The link should also have time validity. Example: link expires after 7 days.

What I have?
User's Email and Employee ID.

Any pointers, how to achieve the above task in C#? or Any other idea, because I just need to User to access application for certain time using Email only.

Comment: Why does it have to be based on their email/id? Just generate a random link and save that in your database along with the user and valid time.

Comment: What have you tried? (http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/), some code would be helpful, as well as why this is something you need?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have gotten it a bit mixed up. The URL cannot be encrypted with the ID or emai. There is little point in using as a key the Employee Id or the email since they are public information.

What you could do is create a random string for the URL and just use the two pieces of information to generate the string. However, once they visit the URL you will need to ask them for a **secret** password in order to log in. Just by visiting the URL and the inputting their email you achieve nothing in terms of security. It is trivial to break such a system by bruteforce if you have access to the emails/employee ids (which you must assume all have).

For the URL based on the email you can xor the two strings and send the output. Then xor the output with the email and get the url.

```
public static string xorIt(string email, string url)
{
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 for(int i=0; i < input.Length; i++)
     sb.Append((char)(url[i] ^ email[(i % key.Length)]));
 String result = sb.ToString ();

 return result;
}
```

a way to check for validity is to store the url in a database along with a timestamp and check at the time of login if it still valid.

There are some caveats with the above approach (e.g. xor always produces the same output for the same two strings but this can be solved if you add a random string and store that string in the table above).

Answer (score 0):

You can't lock this down to their e-mail only, because they could just copy & paste the URL into a browser.

Essentially to get the time-sensitive behaviour, you need to have the following:

1. A database table (or some form of storage) to indicate that this user has been issued a token, and when that token expires
2. A means to generate the cipher-url from the user's e-mail address.

Generating the URL part is easy, in pseudocode you could envision it being as such:

```
var user = GetUser("John.Doe@gmail.com");
var token = EncryptAndHashEmailAddress(user);
var entry = new TokenTableEntry(token:token, expires:DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), User: user.Id);
var url = @"https://www.mywebsite.com/login.aspx?token=" + token;
```

Then when the user clicks the link and hits whatever handles the login request:

```
var token = GetQueryParameter(0); // Get first query parameter
var entry = TokenTable.Element(e => e.Token == token);
TokenTable.Remove(entry);
if (DateTime.Now > entry.Expires)
{
   // Their token has expired
   GoTo("TokenExpired.aspx");
   return;
}
LoginController.UserLoggedIn(entry.Id);
```

This is **very** rough psuedocode, but it should put you on the right tracks.